# Safe value must use [property]=binding after bypass security with DomSanitizer

Tags: javascript, html, angular, security, ionic2

```ts
<!--HTML CODE-->
<p #mass_timings></p>
```

```ts
//Controller code

@ViewChild('mass_timings') mass_timings: ElementRef;
constructor(private domSanitizer:DomSanitizer)
getInnerHTMLValue(){
 this.mass_timings.nativeElement.innerHTML = 
   this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.parishDetail.mass_timings);

}
```

but the output which the mass_timings is displaying is including the text:-

> Safe value must use [property]=binding

at the beginning

How to remove this string.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As the error message says, the sanitized HTML needs to be added using property binding:

```ts
<p [innerHTML]="massTimingsHtml"></p>
```

```ts
constructor(private domSanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
  this.massTimingsHtml = this.getInnerHTMLValue();
}
getInnerHTMLValue(){
  return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.parishDetail.mass_timings);
}
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmxbmy) (based on Swapnil Patwa's Plunker - see comments below)

Comment: @manish kumar, Demo plunker -  https://plnkr.co/edit/oCZ9yKTl68kuTPx6s7fH?p=preview

Comment: did this only.
but can you relate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38826472/7260635) and explain

Comment: You can do that, but not with sanitized HTML, only with a plain HTML string.

Comment: Not if you use `this.mass_timings.nativeElement.innerHTML = ...`. But sanitizing is recommended for security reasons.

Comment: @manishkumar most of the time copying the Plunkers code to StackBlitz will fix it. Plunker based on old Angular versions don't run anymore. See the StackBlitz in my updated Answer.

Comment: I've done this but it's still displaying the error message for some reason, anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? I'm literally using ```this.item = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.item)```
and
```[innerHtml]="item"```

Comment: I guess `this.item` is bound before `this.item = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.item)` is executed. Try using a different field for `...this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.itemHtml)`

Comment: is this the only way? What if we need to add a favicon programatically for example?

Comment: @bubble Not sure what the problem is. This code is mostly about adding CSS or HTML programmatically. Perhaps you can demonstrate the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: I get the exact same error even though I'm doing this.

Answer (score 24):

I was getting this error when using an iframe so there I fixed using `[src]` as below:

**Note: Use pipes for *better* performance**

**Import this:**

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, ....other DI){}
```

**In ts file**

```
getSafeUrl() {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);     
}
```

**In html file**

```
<iframe [src]="getSafeUrl()" frameborder="0" *ngIf="url"></iframe>
```

This method is quite cycle consuming as it'll call the function multiple time so it's better to sanitize URL inside lifeCycleHooks like `ngOnInit()`.

You can use pipes as well for *better performance*:

**Using Pipe**

*HTML:*

```
<iframe [src]="url | byPassSecurity"></iframe>
```

*Sanitize.pipe.ts:*

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'byPassSecurity'
})
export class ByPassSecurityPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform (value: string): SafeHtml {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You just saved my time, thanks! src="{{code}}" doesn't work, but [src]="code" works like a charm!

Comment: After hours of trying, this was finally the solution which worked out for me. Anyone an idea why `src="{{code}}"` doesn't work but `[src]="code"
` does?

Comment: You should use a pipe instead of a function to save performance and prevent it from being called every time the change detection runs. See Renil Babu answer.

Comment: how do you import the pipe??

Comment: You'll need to import it inside the module of the component/page you want to use it in

Answer (score 21):

You need to sanitize() the safevalue like this :

```
this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.parishDetail.mass_timings));
```

Comment: Aren't you just resanitizing?

Comment: I guess sanitize() is happening only once. And it works, that's why i posted.

Comment: It looks funny but this really works! And it's better since you don't need to bind to [innerHtml] everywhere.

Comment: thanks, worked for me on angular 8, ng2-table

Answer (score 8):

My Solution using Pipe.

> HTML

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlValue | byPassSecurity"></div>
```

> Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'byPassSecurity'
})
export class ByPassSecurityPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform (value: string): SafeHtml {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: A pipe is the best solution in terms of performance since a function (like Black Mamba said) will be called each time the change detection runs.

Comment: Great job here, thank you sir!

Answer (score 5):

I got a same error while using MATHJAX in angular 7. I resolved by below pipe transform. 100% work perfectly

//Sanitize HTML PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you underscore sanitizer? Makes no sense. Also you say it works 100% perfectly but no thats not true, some others might use `SecurityContext.URL` for example depending on the context.

Comment: How to apply the same with title of an element

Answer (score 5):

###### You don't need to bind to `[innerHtml]` everywhere.

It works by using `sanitize()` and `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` together like this :

```
this.mass_timings.nativeElement.innerHTML = (
    this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.parishDetail.mass_timings))
);
```