# Need access to Angular 5 directive text

Tags: angular, innerhtml, directive, innertext, elementref

I'm trying to create a custom directive to replace the inner text of my custom directive.  I can't seem to access the inner text content to apply some logic.

Here's the code:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'text-transformer'
})
export class TextTransformerDirective {
  constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef) {
      // need access to inner text before setting new text
      // elem.nativeElement.outerHTML, innerHTML, outerText, innerText are all empty at this point
      elem.nativeElement.outerHTML = '<span>My new Text</span>';
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<text-transformer>Some text</text-transformer>
```

I would like to inspect the text inside the tag, in this case, "Some text".  I can't seem to access it inside the directive.

Should I use component instead?

Comment: Why not just change it to component and test it out?

Comment: Is there a performance difference?

Comment: No, but you're trying to use this directive like a component anyways.

Comment: Probably, I'm migrating from AngularJs (pre-component) to Angular, so component is a newer concept in the current app.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped

Comment: To access element's text it's always best to use a Pipe instead of a directive, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451257/angular-how-to-access-and-replace-innerhtml-from-a-directive/48451891#48451891)

Comment: I agree wit @cyberpirate92 But that is if you want to watch for changes on whatever your transforming value is. Which would be a heavier load, although not a huge deal regardless.

Comment: To manipulate html you'll want a directive not a pipe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're attempting to use a directive like most would use a component.

However, to transform text, it is a directive you want. Just change your selector.

Check out this plunk:

https://plnkr.co/edit/C3SR92TVN1x5bgSazWNW?p=preview

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[text-transformer]'
})
export class TextTransformerDirective implements ngOnInit {

    constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef) {
      // need access to inner text before setting new text
      // elem.nativeElement.outerHTML, innerHTML, outerText, innerText are all empty at this point

    }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.elem.nativeElement.innerText);
    this.elem.nativeElement.innerText += ' !!My new Text!!';
    console.log(this.elem.nativeElement.innerText) 
  }

}
```

Then use that directive from any other component like so:

```
<h1 text-transformer>This text will be changed</h1>
```

And for reference: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: I ran your plunker and I still don't have access to the original text.  Try changing your child component to:
elem.nativeElement.outerHTML += ':My new Text';
and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Oh my bad. Just change it to innerText. There are a bunch of ways to accomplish this. Console log the elem and play with all the properties you want.

Comment: OP can change innerText, he can't get current text

Comment: That += adds it to the current text, therefore, you have the current text..?

Comment: Moved to ngOnInit, so the element can be put into the DOM before we start updating it in the controller constructor. Then you have access to innerText.

Comment: Yeah? that and put the logic in ngOnInit. You could just answer the question yourself ya know?

Comment: Thank you very much @Everett, the ngOnInit was the answer.

Comment: Great! This just answers the question instead of advising a component or whatever. As I came here to find an answer to the question as I need a directive. Awesome, thanks.