# Angular 2 - Textarea sanitization?

Tags: angular

I really dont understand this, the domsanitizer is destroying html in my textarea

I want to bypass the sanitisation, so I use this

```
this.product['name_fr'] = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.product['name_fr']);
```

but in my textarea

```
<input class="productNameInput" [(ngModel)]="product.name_fr" [formControl]="nameValidatorFr"/>
```

this appears

```
SafeValue must use [property]=binding: fds fds fds fds ds (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

and in DB my string is stored empty

can someone enlight me on this ? I want to KEEP html intact

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351434/safe-value-must-use-property-binding-after-bypass-security-with-domsanitizer

Comment: I already read that, it does not seem related, I iuse a textarea, so an ngModel

Comment: are you trying to put html inside textarea?

Comment: no, I use an ngModel , see the code above...when I click on a save button, I do this.product['name_fr'] = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.product['name_fr']);

Comment: try this this.product ={ name_fr:this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.product['name_fr'])};

Comment: I already do this this.product['name_fr'] = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.product['name_fr']);