# Angular 8: how to use ngFor without html tags. I tried ng-container but it not works

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-container

After I faced lot of issues I created this following idea to make a fill in the blanks question in my angular project. The objects shown below are getting from API and I want to loop it like this below I mentioned. I am unable to use `ng-container` tag instead of `span` because it creates depreciated html tags issue. Reason for that, The tags I mentioned in the array which will not be closed in the same object and it will be closed by next or next of next object of given array named as field. I mean, If the `0`th order has a value `<p>my text` and the `1`st order will have the value `is this </p>`.

The following code works

```
            <div *ngIf="fill.type == 'lines'" >
              <span *ngFor="let f of fill.field">

                <span *ngIf="f.word_type == 'word'" [innerHTML]="makeSanitize(f.word)"></span>
                <span *ngIf="f.word_type == 'blank'"><input type="text" (keyup)="updateinput($event, f, miniq)" value="" [class.bg-success]="f.myanswer == f.word && miniq.answered && miniq.verified" [class.bg-danger]="f.myanswer != f.word && miniq.answered && miniq.verified" /></span>

              </span>
            </div>
```

But The following code give some error

```
            <div *ngIf="fill.type == 'lines'" >
              <ng-container *ngFor="let f of fill.field">

                <ng-container *ngIf="f.word_type == 'word'" [innerHTML]="makeSanitize(f.word)"></ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngIf="f.word_type == 'blank'"><input type="text" (keyup)="updateinput($event, f, miniq)" value="" [class.bg-success]="f.myanswer == f.word && miniq.answered && miniq.verified" [class.bg-danger]="f.myanswer != f.word && miniq.answered && miniq.verified" /></ng-container>

              </ng-container>
            </div>
```

[image]

JSON Response of this loop is

```
type: "lines",
field:

      0: {word: "<p>during table - "
          word_type: "word"
          myanswer: ""},
      1: {word: "apple"
          word_type: "blank"
          myanswer: ""},
      2: {word: " answer1</p>
          ↵
          ↵<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;- answer2</p>
          ↵
          ↵<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;- "
          word_type: "word"
          myanswer: ""},
      3: {word: "orange"
          word_type: "blank"
          myanswer: ""},
      4: {word: " answer3</p>
          ↵
          ↵<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;- test 
          answer4</p>"
          word_type: "word"
          myanswer: ""}
```

Anyone please help me how to use it without tags or how to make `ng-container` to work

Comment: You can't bind to [innerHTML] of an ng-container because it doesn't actually appear in the DOM. `The Angular <ng-container> is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.` - from the angular docs.

Comment: Is anyother way to solve this issue?

Comment: And what is the issue? Why not use `div` or `span`?

Comment: Please check the value of ```word:``` and ```word_type``` from the JSON. The method I used will create some tag closing issue If I used span. I don't want use any tags instead of span

Answer (score 0):

You cant bind to `innerHTML` since it's not a property of `ng-container` as th error message already suggests. Use databinding instead, that should fix the issue. ( **{{ makeSanitize(f.word) }}** )

```
            <ng-container *ngIf="f.word_type == 'word'">{{ makeSanitize(f.word) }}</ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="f.word_type == 'blank'">
                <input type="text" (keyup)="updateinput($event, f, miniq)" value="" [class.bg-success]="f.myanswer == f.word && miniq.answered && miniq.verified" [class.bg-danger]="f.myanswer != f.word && miniq.answered && miniq.verified" />
            </ng-container>

          </ng-container>
```

Comment: I am getting ```SafeValue must use [property]=binding: <p>during table - (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)```

Comment: Can you try using `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(makeSanitize(f.word))`?

Comment: I am getting nothing

Comment: did you inject the DomSanitizer in your component? `constructor(protected readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}` ?

Comment: Please look at this function I already used ```  makeSanitize(str: any)
  {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(str);
    // return str;
  }```

Comment: try using it unsanitized, else use the div version... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351434/safe-value-must-use-property-binding-after-bypass-security-with-domsanitizer

Answer (score 0):

Change ng-container to ng-template.

```
<div *ngIf="fill.type == 'lines'" >
              <ng-container *ngFor="let f of fill.field">

                <ng-template [ngIf]="f.word_type == 'word'" [innerHTML]="makeSanitize(f.word)"></ng-template>
                <ng-template [ngIf]="f.word_type == 'blank'"><input type="text" (keyup)="updateinput($event, f, miniq)" value="" [class.bg-success]="f.myanswer == f.word && miniq.answered && miniq.verified" [class.bg-danger]="f.myanswer != f.word && miniq.answered && miniq.verified" /></ng-template>

              </ng-container>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want use ```div```. If used div the output will make some html closing error

Comment: what about ng-template?

Comment: Edited my answer using ng-template.

Comment: It give blank output bro

Comment: @ArunKumar I am getting error like this by after added the edited update of your answer bro ```ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Property binding innerHTML not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
              <ng-container *ngFor="let f of fill.field">

                [ERROR ->]<ng-template [ngIf]="f.word_type == 'word'" [innerHTML]="makeSanitize(f.word)"></ng-template>```

Comment: @mbojko The Response comes from admin using ckeditor via API